# Custom Expression Function: ParseDateTime

Tags: datetime, spotfire

Given a DateTime of

> 10-OCT-2015 07:10 PM

How can one convert this? I've got the first part correct but it's the Time I'm having difficulty with.

```
ParseDateTime([column name],"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm")
```

How can AM/PM be represented?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!

```
ParseDateTime([Diary Date],"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt","en-US")
```